# Is there a way to make the firestore search results into an array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make an array from the search results of a query search in firestore.

The results from a query search from something like

```
  docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        var dataArray =  doc.data();
        var arrayOutputs = [dataArray];

         var name = arrayOutputs[0].Name;

        console.log(name);

      });
    });
```

Will return all of the results where there are three results given which it shows up but I am trying to put each of the Objects into one array. Pulling the search results separately if needed and using it for a "for loop".

thank you

Comment: So, is `arrayOutputs` the three return results? If so, what exactly do you want to do with them? It's a little bit unclear currently.

Comment: yes the `arrayOutputs` is the three return results, I would like to pull data that comes from the searches and put it in html elements and generate cards of info that is displayed

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If `dataArray` is each document you are fetching, just add them to an array, or do your UI inside the `forEach` function, no?

Answer (score 1):

The OP code assigns `arrayOutputs` to a single element array on each iteration. To get an array of results, map over the returned docs, getting `data()` from each...

```
docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
   let allDocData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
   console.log(JSON.stringify(allDocData));
});
```

**Edit** Same idea with a for loop rather than map...

```
docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    let allDocData = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        allDocData.push(doc.data());
    });
    console.log(`we found ${allDocData.length} docs as follows...`);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(allDocData));
});
```

Comment: It works but when I try to do a for loop it does not recognize it as an array when I try to do `allDocData.length`

Comment: @JafferAbyanSyed based on the OP code, there's a good chance your for-loop has a mistake.  I edited to include an example using the query snapshot's forEach method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push the result to an array, do:

```
docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    var myArray = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        myArray.push(doc.data());
    });
});
```